# Unable to find button element for python (3.9.6) selenium/chrome webscraper to accept cookies popup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a web-scraper to get some stats to monitor. After getting the very basics down with *requests* and *beautifulsoup* to scrape a simple page, I realised my actual target page is far from basic! The main page is populated from javascript which needs to run/render on the page - and before I even get there - I need the session to accept/click a cookie popup and then pass a log-in screen. This has led me to try *selenium* to navigate with headless Chrome. It didn't seem too bad, but I can't seem to access the elements (buttons and user/password fields) as expected; perhaps these are in iFrames? But now I'm lost and trying to hit iFrames / IDs / NAMEs / XPaths by stabbing in the dark.

The initial landing page I want to hit is: https://mygas.airliquide.fr/user/login?

the script is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Configure Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Enable headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# Set up the Chrome webdriver with the configured options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Load the login webpage
driver.get("https://mygas.airliquide.fr/user/login?")

# Accept the cookies popup (if present)
try:
    cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "awe-popkies-banner-bt_agree"))) 
    cookies_button.click()
    print("Cookies accepted")
except:
    print("Cookies EXCEPTION")
    pass

# Perform login with provided credentials
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"

username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "name")))
password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "pass")))

username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "edit-submit")
login_button.click()


# Wait for the JavaScript script to run and populate the page (modify the timeout value as needed)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "Title")))

# Scrape the particular HTML element based on its tag
element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "Title")
text = element.get_attribute("textContent")

print("Scraped element text:", text)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Running it like this, I get the following error:

```
Cookies EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/James/Desktop/scrape_test/reddit.py", line 40, in <module>
    login_button.click()
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 94, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" value="Sign in" name="op" id="edit-submit" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="1">...</button> is not clickable at point (1091, 451). Other element would receive the click: <div class="awe-popkies-content-container" style="display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.126)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x00000001008e78ac chromedriver + 4257964
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001008dff40 chromedriver + 4226880
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010051c9d4 chromedriver + 281044
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010055e134 chromedriver + 549172
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010055c094 chromedriver + 540820
5   chromedriver                        0x0000000100559fac chromedriver + 532396
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010055937c chromedriver + 529276
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010054d984 chromedriver + 481668
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010054d1cc chromedriver + 479692
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010058e7e4 chromedriver + 747492
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010054b98c chromedriver + 473484
11  chromedriver                        0x000000010054c98c chromedriver + 477580
12  chromedriver                        0x00000001008a6900 chromedriver + 3991808
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001008aa354 chromedriver + 4006740
14  chromedriver                        0x00000001008aa940 chromedriver + 4008256
15  chromedriver                        0x00000001008b033c chromedriver + 4031292
16  chromedriver                        0x00000001008aaf34 chromedriver + 4009780
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000100883490 chromedriver + 3847312
18  chromedriver                        0x00000001008c89f4 chromedriver + 4131316
19  chromedriver                        0x00000001008c8b4c chromedriver + 4131660
20  chromedriver                        0x00000001008d9230 chromedriver + 4198960
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000194f0906c _pthread_start + 148
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000194f03e2c thread_start + 8
```

Which to me indicates I'm not clearing the cookie popup, but I don't know how to get at it.

Any help and suggestions are really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie accept button locator was not correct, changed it to below and worked fine in headless and non-headless mode

```
By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.awe-popkies-bt_agree'
```

Full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Configure Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Enable headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# Set up the Chrome webdriver with the configured options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
# Load the login webpage
driver.get("https://mygas.airliquide.fr/user/login?")

# Accept the cookies popup (if present)

cookies_button = wait.until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.awe-popkies-bt_agree')))
cookies_button.click()
print("Cookies accepted")

# Perform login with provided credentials
username = ""
password = ""

username_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "name")))
password_input = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "pass")))

username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "edit-submit")
login_button.click()

# Wait for the JavaScript script to run and populate the page (modify the timeout value as needed)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "Title")))

# Scrape the particular HTML element based on its tag
element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "Title")
text = element.get_attribute("textContent")

print("Scraped element text:", text)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: please accept then answer if your issue is resolved